# XAMPP MySQL shutdown unexpectedly (no blocked port)

Tags: mysql, xampp

Between the last time it worked and now I have done nothing special that would somehow break it. But now it gives me this message:

```
11:37:07  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:37:07  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:37:07  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:37:07  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:37:07  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:37:07  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:37:07  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

I have had this before. Usually it appears when the MySQL port (3306) is blocked. I just stop the process using it then. One time my InnoDB was corrupted or something like that, but I managed to fix that too. But now my log files show absolutely nothing that could help somehow. It exactly matches with logs from earlier when it worked.

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data_minecraft\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data_minecraft\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.17 started; log sequence number 17593598; transaction id 64665
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data_minecraft\ib_buffer_pool
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-01-16 11:27:36 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I rebooted my PC several times and started MySQL with the innodb_force_recovery set to every value from 0 to 3, no luck either. Does any of you know what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In the "mysql/data" folder (you might want to back it up), I deleted every file that had "relay-bin", "relay-log" or "master" in its name. I can't explain why this worked. I just thought that MySQL got stuck in trying to read those files and creating new ones, however that's what worked for me.